# Complete Userform to enable command button

Tags: excel, vba, userform, commandbutton

I have the following code to complete a userform, and the information is then submitted on the corresponding worksheet selected in the ListBox. I have the command button that submits the info enabled only if a worksheet has been selected from the ListBox. I need help doing the same for every TextBox so that users are forced to complete the form in its entirety before submitting it. Thanks for the help.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        CommandButton1.Enabled = False
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            ListBox1.AddItem (ws.Name)
        Next ws
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    CommandButton1.Enabled = ListBox1.ListIndex <> -1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    whichSheet = ListBox1.Value
    Dim n As Integer

    Do
        n = n + 1
        ListBox1.AddItem Sheets(n).Name
    Loop Until n = Worksheets.Count

    Worksheets(whichSheet).Activate
    Dim lastrow
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    lastrow = lastrow + 1
    Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1
    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to add the record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Add Record")
    If answer = vbYes Then
        Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1.Text
        Cells(lastrow, 2) = TextBox2.Text
        Cells(lastrow, 3) = TextBox4.Text
        Cells(lastrow, 4) = TextBox5.Text
        Cells(lastrow, 5) = TextBox6.Text
    Else
        Cells(lastrow, 1) = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Write a function (eg) `AllTextboxesAreFilled` which returns false if any of the textboxes are empty, then  add a Change event handler to each textbox which does this `CommandButton1.Enabled = AllTextboxesAreFilled()`

Comment: Why do this just before asking the user if they want to save the record ? `Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1`

Comment: You're right I can delete that

Comment: Which private sub should I include the function?

Comment: Just create a new Function in the form's code module.